# Get serializer field value in api-view

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to get a field value from a serialized object in Django Rest Framework? Something like this:

```
serializer = PostSerializer(post)
print(serializer.title)
# 'foo title'
```

I need this for fields that are added in the serializer, but are not already on the model, like if the logged in user has liked the post.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I figured it out myself, you need to reference the "data" class inside the serializer:

```
serializer.data['title']
```

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal It seems you are applying serializer.data['title'] on query list. This will work if its object.

Comment: AssertionError: When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the serialized `.data` representation.

Answer (score 3):

Before .save method you should use validated_data to access fields

```
serialiser.validated_data['title']
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it to get the Python value out.  The other answer doesn't give what one might need: `S(data={'date': '2020-02-02'}).data['date']` results in `'2020-02-02'` rather than a `datetime.date`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can get data from API by

```
serializer = StudentSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        email = serializer.data['email']
```

After that you can use this data in your API view.